# some batch file questions

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have 3 questions on the topic of batch files.

Firstly I want to append the following at filename YYYYMMDDHHMM - how can I get this value in a bat file?

Secondly, using XCOPY how can I move a file to a subfolder without being prompted for any user input?

Finally, I have a number of actions in my bat file so want implement some error handing ie. if first action fails, abort rest and show message to the user. Any tips as to how i can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have three different questions, then please post three different questions. It's what this site is for. There is no limit for how many questions you can ask.

Comment: You asked "...XCOPY how can I move a file...". AFAIK XCOPY can't move files, it'll only copy files to another destination, leaving the original files as they were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The easiest way of getting the current date and time in a locale-neutral format is `wmic os get LocalDateTime`:

   ```
   for /f "skip=1" %%d in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%d
   rem Only leave date, hours and minutes
   set MyDate=%MyDate:~0,12%
   ```
2. `xcopy` has a `/i` switch:

   ```
   /I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one file,
                assumes that destination must be a directory.
   ```

   If that doesn't apply, then you can just use `copy`. `robocopy` might allow finer-grained control, even.
3. Just check after each command whether it was successfully:

   ```
   if errorlevel 1 goto error
   ```

   and put the following at the end of your batch file:

   ```
   goto :eof
   :error
   echo An error occurred.
   exit /b 1
   ```